# One of the screen has purple filter

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, screen, night-light

I'm using 3 screen with my computer. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. But one of the screen has purple filter. I already tried to turn on/off "night light", but didn't work. how can close this filter? or how can i understand is it hardware of software problem?

Note: this problem not happen when i switch to windows.

Comment: Possibly a hardware problem. But you have given no information about the connection type of these "screens". Do you mean HDMI or USB connected monitors?

Comment: @FedKad HDMI connection

Comment: Solved: Settings>color>add profile> sRGB and delete automatic. This solution worked for me.

Comment: You can add your own answer by giving a little bit more detail and accept it.